# Intuition about the relation of combinations and entropy

Tags: combinatorics, intuition, information-theory, coding-theory, entropy

It is not difficult to show that 
$${n \choose \lambda n} \leq 2^{H(\lambda)n}$$
where $H$ is the binary entropy function:
$$H(\alpha) = -\alpha \lg \alpha - (1-\alpha)\lg (1-\alpha)$$

I was wondering if there is an intuition about this relation between ${n \choose \lambda n}$ and the entropy of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is: The left-hand side is the number of states available to a system with a fixed number $\lambda n$ of particles distributed over $n$ sites whereas the right-hand side is the effective number of states available to a system of $n$ sites independently occupied with probability $\lambda$. It's intuitively clear that the latter system has more states available, since the particle number is allowed to vary. The difference is related to the one between the [canonical ensemble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_ensemble) and the [grand canonical ensemble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_canonical_ensemble). Alternatively, you can regard the sites as possible excitations of equal energy; then the difference is related to the one between the [microcanonical ensemble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcanonical_ensemble) and the canonical ensemble.

The binary entropy $-\sum_ip_i\lg p_i$ is the binary logarithm of the effective number of states. The binary entropy of the system with fixed particle number $\lambda n$ is

$$
-\binom n{\lambda n}\left(\binom n{\lambda n}^{-1}\lg\binom n{\lambda n}^{-1}\right)=\lg\binom n{\lambda n},
$$

whereas the binary entropy of the system with given proportion $\lambda$ is the sum of the binary entropies of the $n$ independent systems, and $H(\lambda)$ is precisely the entropy of a site with two states, occupied with probability $\lambda$ and unoccupied with probability $1-\lambda$; the sum for all $n$ sites is $H(\lambda)n$.

Comment: Very nice, thank you :)

Comment: @Kaveh: You're welcome!